# Ruby on rails api unable to delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have used scaffold to generate simple application, I'm able to perform GET and POST via chrome extension tool called "PostMan", However I'm unable to perform DELETE action via this tool, I'm getting:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/settings.json/18"
```

I have checked routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :settings
```

And deleting record via default scaffold works, only when I'm performing an API call.

Console log displays the following:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/settings.json/18"):
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
```

I'm not sure what else to check, any input is hightly appreicate it.

Comment: your resources are `:settings` so `/settings.json/18` won't work. Try `/settings/18.json`

Comment: You are correct, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with the path, it should be `"/settings/18.json"` instead of `"/settings.json/18"`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help